# Can the authorised client IDs be dynamic?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My app will have a large number of authorised client applications that may access the API, and this list will be constantly changing (well at least that's what the business plan says :-) ).

Is it possible to have the array of authorised clients driven from stored data. I'm not keen on having to change the code and redeploy every time we authorise a new client application.

Comment: you cannot change the list dynamically as you need need to predefine the authorised client ids in your endpoints class or methods. Also you cannot dynamically add more clients in your api console as each client will required a seperate client id unlike an api key. Can you please add details of your requirement like what type of clients , why different clients , etc so as to see if there is any other solution?

Comment: I need to be a little coy about the use case for commercial reasons. For want of a better analogy, think Facebook or Evernote. These services have many registered client applications that are authorised to use their APIs. If a developer wants to register his app to use FB, the FB engineers don't recompile their code and republish it. I can (just) live with the manual intervention on the API console, but I don't want to have to edit/compile/test/deploy my app every time a new developer wants to integrate to my service.